# Azure Resource Manager deployment timeouts

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-resource-manager, azure-diagnostics, azure-vm-scale-set

I keep seeing timeouts when using Azure Resource Manager to deploy a Service Fabric Cluster. I see the error below, probably about 20% of the time. Re-deploying the same configuration will fix the problem.

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 6:54:02 AM - Resource Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets 'nodeType' failed 
with message '{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "VMExtensionHandlerNonTransientError",
        "message": "Handler 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.ServiceFabricNode' has reported failure for VM Extension 
'nodeType_ServiceFabricNode' with terminal error code '1009' and error message: 'Enable failed for plugin (name: 
Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.ServiceFabricNode, version 1.0.0.35) with exception Command 
C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.ServiceFabricNode\\1.0.0.35\\ServiceFabricExtensionHandler.exe of 
Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.ServiceFabricNode has not exited on time! Killing it...'"
      }
    ]
  }
}'
At C:\BuildAgent\work\d851d22c9abed7b9\Core\Core\scripts\Provision\ProvisionGeneric.ps1:39 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Verbose -ResourceGroupName $resou ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep 
   loymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 6:54:02 AM - Handler 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.ServiceFabricNode' has 
reported failure for VM Extension 'nodeType_ServiceFabricNode' with terminal error code '1009' and error message: 'Enable 
failed for plugin (name: Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.ServiceFabricNode, version 1.0.0.35) with exception Command 
C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.ServiceFabricNode\1.0.0.35\ServiceFabricExtensionHandler.exe of 
Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.ServiceFabricNode has not exited on time! Killing it...'
At C:\BuildAgent\work\d851d22c9abed7b9\Core\Core\scripts\Provision\ProvisionGeneric.ps1:39 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Verbose -ResourceGroupName $resou ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep 
   loymentCmdlet
```

The relevant part of the Azure RM template looks like this:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "[variables('vmssApiVersion')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets",
    "name": "[parameters('vmNodeType0Name')]",
    "location": "[parameters('computeLocation')]",
    "dependsOn": ["[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('uniqueStringArray0')[0])]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('uniqueStringArray0')[1])]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('uniqueStringArray0')[2])]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('uniqueStringArray0')[3])]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('uniqueStringArray0')[4])]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/', concat('INT_LB','-', parameters('clusterName'),'-',parameters('vmNodeType0Name')))]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/', concat('EXT_LB','-', parameters('clusterName'),'-',parameters('vmNodeType0Name')))]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('supportLogStorageAccountName'))]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('applicationDiagnosticsStorageAccountName'))]"],
    "properties": {
        "overprovision": "[parameters('overProvision')]",
        "upgradePolicy": {
            "mode": "Automatic"
        },
        "virtualMachineProfile": {
            "extensionProfile": {
                "extensions": [{
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('vmNodeType0Name'),'_ServiceFabricNode')]",
                    "properties": {
                        "type": "ServiceFabricNode",
                        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": false,
                        "protectedSettings": {
                            "StorageAccountKey1": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('supportLogStorageAccountName')),'2015-05-01-preview').key1]",
                            "StorageAccountKey2": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('supportLogStorageAccountName')),'2015-05-01-preview').key2]"
                        },
                        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric",
                        "settings": {
                            "clusterEndpoint": "[reference(parameters('clusterName')).clusterEndpoint]",
                            "nodeTypeRef": "[parameters('vmNodeType0Name')]",
                            "dataPath": "D:\\\\SvcFab",
                            "durabilityLevel": "Bronze",
                            "certificate": {
                                "thumbprint": "[parameters('clusterSecurityCertThumbprint')]",
                                "x509StoreName": "my"
                            }
                        },
                        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.0"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "[concat('VMDiagnosticsVmExt','_vmNodeType0Name')]",
                    "properties": {
                        "type": "IaaSDiagnostics",
                        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                        "protectedSettings": {
                            "storageAccountName": "[parameters('applicationDiagnosticsStorageAccountName')]",
                            "storageAccountKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('applicationDiagnosticsStorageAccountName')),'2015-05-01-preview').key1]",
                            "storageAccountEndPoint": "https://core.windows.net/"
                        },
                        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics",
                        "settings": {
                            "WadCfg": {
                                "DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration": {
                                    "overallQuotaInMB": "50000",
                                    "sinks": "ApplicationInsights",
                                    "DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs": {
                                        "scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter": "Error"
                                    },
                                    "EtwProviders": {
                                        "EtwEventSourceProviderConfiguration": [{
                                            "provider": "Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Actors",
                                            "scheduledTransferKeywordFilter": "1",
                                            "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M",
                                            "DefaultEvents": {
                                                "eventDestination": "ServiceFabricReliableActorEvents"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "provider": "Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Services",
                                            "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M",
                                            "DefaultEvents": {
                                                "eventDestination": "ServiceFabricReliableServiceEvents"
                                            }
                                        }],
                                        "EtwManifestProviderConfiguration": [{
                                            "provider": "cbd93bc2-71e5-4566-b3a7-595d8eeca6e8",
                                            "scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter": "Information",
                                            "scheduledTransferKeywordFilter": "4611686018427387904",
                                            "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M",
                                            "DefaultEvents": {
                                                "eventDestination": "ServiceFabricSystemEventTable"
                                            }
                                        }]
                                    }
                                },
                                "SinksConfig": {
                                    "Sink": [{
                                        "name": "ApplicationInsights",
                                        "ApplicationInsights": "[parameters('appInsightsKey')]",
                                        "Channels": {
                                            "Channel": [{
                                                "logLevel": "Error",
                                                "name": "Errors"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "logLevel": "Verbose",
                                                "name": "AppLogs"
                                            }]
                                        }
                                    }]
                                }
                            },
                            "StorageAccount": "[parameters('applicationDiagnosticsStorageAccountName')]"
                        },
                        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.5"
                    }
                }]
            },
            "networkProfile": {
                "networkInterfaceConfigurations": [{
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('nicName'), '-0')]",
                    "properties": {
                        "ipConfigurations": [{
                            "name": "[concat(parameters('nicName'),'-',0)]",
                            "properties": {
                                "loadBalancerBackendAddressPools": [{
                                    "id": "[variables('lbIntPoolId')]"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "[variables('lbExtPoolId')]"
                                }],
                                "subnet": {
                                    "id": "[variables('subnet0Ref')]"
                                }
                            }
                        }],
                        "primary": true
                    }
                }]
            },
            "osProfile": {
                "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]",
                "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
                "computernamePrefix": "[parameters('vmNodeType0Name')]",
                "secrets": [{
                    "sourceVault": {
                        "id": "[parameters('keyVaultName')]"
                    },
                    "vaultCertificates": [{
                        "certificateStore": "my",
                        "certificateUrl": "[parameters('encyphermentCertId')]"
                    },
                    {
                        "certificateStore": "my",
                        "certificateUrl": "[parameters('identityServerSigningCertId')]"
                    },
                    {
                        "certificateStore": "my",
                        "certificateUrl": "[parameters('clusterSecurityCertId')]"
                    },
                    {
                        "certificateStore": "My",
                        "certificateUrl": "[parameters('adminCertId')]"
                    },
                    {
                        "certificateStore": "CertificateAuthority",
                        "certificateUrl": "[parameters('clusterSecurityCertId')]"
                    }]
                }]
            },
            "storageProfile": {
                "imageReference": {
                    "publisher": "[parameters('vmImagePublisher')]",
                    "offer": "[parameters('vmImageOffer')]",
                    "sku": "[parameters('vmImageSku')]",
                    "version": "[parameters('vmImageVersion')]"
                },
                "osDisk": {
                    "vhdContainers": ["[concat('https://', variables('uniqueStringArray0')[0], '.blob.core.windows.net/', parameters('vmStorageAccountContainerName'))]",
                    "[concat('https://', variables('uniqueStringArray0')[1], '.blob.core.windows.net/', parameters('vmStorageAccountContainerName'))]",
                    "[concat('https://', variables('uniqueStringArray0')[2], '.blob.core.windows.net/', parameters('vmStorageAccountContainerName'))]",
                    "[concat('https://', variables('uniqueStringArray0')[3], '.blob.core.windows.net/', parameters('vmStorageAccountContainerName'))]",
                    "[concat('https://', variables('uniqueStringArray0')[4], '.blob.core.windows.net/', parameters('vmStorageAccountContainerName'))]"],
                    "name": "vmssosdisk",
                    "caching": "ReadOnly",
                    "createOption": "FromImage"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('vmNodeType0Size')]",
        "capacity": "[parameters('vmNodeType0Count')]",
        "tier": "Standard"
    },
    "tags": {
        "resourceType": "Service Fabric",
        "clusterName": "[parameters('clusterName')]"
    }
},
```

It seems to happen more in the morning than any other time. It's causing our CI build to fail on a regular basis. How can I diagnose this problem? If it's just something we should expect, then what is the best way to capture the error to force a re-deploy?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not changing anything between deployments it's not likely anything you're doing wrong...  Open a support request in the Azure portal and give them one of your correlationIds from the failed deployments (more if you have 'em).